# Why does my hair only grow on the edge? I can't solve this problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, vertices, hair

Why does my hair only grow on the edge? I can't solve this problem[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to say, maybe share your file (just the useful object): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=S7bbpYrR" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/S7bbpYrR/)